# How to fix Gradle not recognizing Java 10 on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, gradle

When working with the latest Gradle version with Java 10 on Linux, it fails to identify version number of Java as 10 as valid Java version. How to fix this problem on Linux machines ? Log details of the error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zBPb.png)

And here is the complete error report (N.B. Running `gradle --version` or `gradle -v` also gives the same output :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '10'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

EDIT :
Output of `gradle --stacktrace`

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '10'.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not determine java version from '10'.
at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.toVersion(JavaVersion.java:70)
at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.current(JavaVersion.java:80)
at org.gradle.internal.jvm.UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException.assertUsingVersion(UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException.java:29)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:32)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
```

Output of java --version

```
java 10 2018-03-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10+46)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10+46, mixed mode)
```

Comment: The description is too vague. What were you doing exactly, what did you expect and what happened instead.

Comment: I have added text and image descriptions on the problem. Hope it clears up the question

Comment: What does the --stacktrace option show?

Comment: can you please provide output of `gradle -version`, `java --version`,
`java -version`?

Comment: I have added all the required outputs in an edit, please go through them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to upgrade Gradle. Version 4.5.1 and later definitely support Java 10.

If you think you have 4.5.1 or later installed, but `gradle -version` still won't run, it's possible that when you type `gradle` at the command line, it's still running an older version for some reason.

One common thing to do is alias `gradle` to `./gradlew`, so that in the context of a Gradle project, you'll use the wrapper Gradle rather than the system Gradle. This is usually helpful, but in a situation like this, it backfires. You should be able to determine the installed system Gradle with `which`:

```
> which gradle
/usr/local/bin/gradle
> $(which gradle) -version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.6
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-02-28 13:36:36 UTC
Revision:     8fa6ce7945b640e6168488e4417f9bb96e4ab46c

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
JVM:          10.0.1 ("Oracle Corporation" 10.0.1+10)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.13.4 x86_64
```

(I've elided some warnings about illegal reflective access, if you get those, don't worry about them.)

If `$(which gradle) -version` still won't run, you need to upgrade the system gradle. But if it does, to update the Gradle wrapper, you can edit your `build.gradle` --

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion = '4.6'
}
```

-- and then use the system Gradle to rerun the `wrapper` task:

```
> $(which gradle) wrapper
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 7s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
> ./gradlew -version
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-bin.zip
......................................................................

[etc.]

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.6
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-02-28 13:36:36 UTC
Revision:     8fa6ce7945b640e6168488e4417f9bb96e4ab46c

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
JVM:          10.0.1 ("Oracle Corporation" 10.0.1+10)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.13.4 x86_64
```

Answer (score 2):

Take help of ppa and upgrade your gradle version , Ubuntu 17 comes with gradle `sudo apt install gradle` will install default gradle version.

to upgrade for java 10 need to run below command.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cwchien/gradle
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt upgrade gradle
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Guys I Found the problem in this case. I installed gradle from the official debian repositories which contained an outdated version of gradle which didn't support Java 10. On downloading and installing Gradle from the [official site](https://gradle.org/releases/) and soft linking it to the /usr/bin/gradle , it worked just fine. So the problem essentially was installing gradle from the debian repositories which are currently outdated.